# How to modify DAX ALLEXCEPT to allow filtering

Tags: dax

I have a Table called Tracking, as shown below:

| Category | Item Id | Work Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1/1/2020 |
| B | 1 | 2/1/2020 |
| C | 1 | 3/1/2020 |
| D | 1 | 4/1/2020 |
| A | 2 | 7/1/2020 |
| B | 2 | 8/1/2020 |
| C | 2 | 9/1/2020 |
| D | 2 | 10/1/2020 |

Using the below measure, I can get Maximum Work Date from the above Table.

```
maxWorkDate =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'Tracking'[Work Date] ),
    ALLEXCEPT (
        'Tracking',
        'Tracking'[Item Id]
    )
)
```

For Item 1, the maximum work date is 4/1/2020 and for Item 2, the maximum work date is 10/1/2020.

I want to get maximum work date by Excluding Category D. So, For Item 1, the maximum work date should be 3/1/2020 and for Item 2, the maximum work date should be 9/1/2020.

I would like to exclude category D within the measure or I can also exclude it in Visual Filters. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to implement the measure with a filter expression `'Tracking'[Category] <> "D"` like follows

```
maxWorkDate =
CALCULATE(
    MAX( 'Tracking'[Work Date] ),
    REMOVEFILTERS( 'Tracking' ),
    VALUES( 'Tracking'[Item Id] ),
    'Tracking'[Category] <> "D"
)
```

Comment: Hi, then you can accept the answer by clicking on the V sign on top left :) Please, read this to better enjoy your experience in the stack overflow community https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

This is what [FILTER](https://dax.guide/filter/) is for:

```
maxWorkDate =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'Tracking'[Work Date] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLEXCEPT (
            'Tracking',
            'Tracking'[Item Id]
        ),
        'Tracking'[Category] <> "D"
    )
)
```